# How to trigger a full backup with Time Machine

Tags: time-machine

Is there any way that I can trigger a full backup with Time Machine? I am hoping for a backup which backs up all files on my computer, as opposed to just the changes in those files relative to that last Time Machine backup. I'm using MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra.

Comment: TM is designed to do incremental backups. Which problem are you trying to solve with a forced full backup?

Comment: If you look at the backup in Time Machine you will see a full backup. Now TM has generated that using incremental backups but that does not affect the end result you won"t be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Each Time Machine snapshot is a full backup, made up of "all the files that have changed since the previous backup" and "links to all the files that stayed the same as the previous backup". The links are indistinguishable from the original files. Why do you want what you ask for? What files do you think are missing?

Answer (score 3):

Time Machine will only start a completely new backup if it's the first backup to that drive/partition.

So, your choices are

1. A separate drive or new partition on the existing drive.
2. A change of tactic [which would also require a new drive or partition] a single backup using something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com)

At High Sierra, I'd recommend the first if you need it for a future migration, but the second if you want a solid disaster recovery backup.

Comment: I've got to take exception wrt the [CCC](https://bombich.com/) reccomendation. I used it a few years ago, and found it to be bordering on useless, and certainly poorly-documented.

Comment: @Seamus - been using it maybe a decade. Never had any issues. Does what it says on the tin. Not tried it with anything brand new - M1 etc. Seems Apple are making life much harder for those.

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you.